# "error":"UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.\n\tstatus code: 403 - AWS loadbalancer controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I'm trying to make an AWS network load balancer via Kubernetes service. As a pre-requisite, I followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html) whole article from AWS. The controller is deployed smoothly, but when I apply the Kubernetes service via the following annotations,

```
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations: eipalloc-x.x.x.x,
  eipalloc-x.x.x.x, eipalloc-x.x.x.x
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: ip
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: subnet-yyyyy,
  subnet-yyyyy, subnet-yyyyy
```

Getting the following error:

```
"error":"UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.\n\tstatus code: 403
```

**aws-load-balancer-controller-service-account.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/name: aws-load-balancer-controller
  name: aws-load-balancer-controller
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::588213647772:role/AmazonEKSLoadBalancerControllerRole
```

**load-balancer-role-trust-policy.json:**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::acc_id:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/oidc_id"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/oidc_id:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com",
                "oidc.eks.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/id/oidc_id:sub": "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:aws-load-balancer-controller"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

**iam-policy.json:**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "iam:AWSServiceName": "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes",
            "ec2:DescribeAddresses",
            "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
            "ec2:DescribeInternetGateways",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcPeeringConnections",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
            "ec2:DescribeTags",
            "ec2:GetCoipPoolUsage",
            "ec2:DescribeCoipPools",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancerAttributes",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListeners",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeListenerCertificates",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeSSLPolicies",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeRules",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroups",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetGroupAttributes",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTargetHealth",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeTags"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient",
            "acm:ListCertificates",
            "acm:DescribeCertificate",
            "iam:ListServerCertificates",
            "iam:GetServerCertificate",
            "waf-regional:GetWebACL",
            "waf-regional:GetWebACLForResource",
            "waf-regional:AssociateWebACL",
            "waf-regional:DisassociateWebACL",
            "wafv2:GetWebACL",
            "wafv2:GetWebACLForResource",
            "wafv2:AssociateWebACL",
            "wafv2:DisassociateWebACL",
            "shield:GetSubscriptionState",
            "shield:DescribeProtection",
            "shield:CreateProtection",
            "shield:DeleteProtection"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
            "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:CreateTags"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:CreateAction": "CreateSecurityGroup"
            },
            "Null": {
                "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:CreateTags",
            "ec2:DeleteTags"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "true",
                "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
            "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
            "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elasticloadbalancing:CreateLoadBalancer",
            "elasticloadbalancing:CreateTargetGroup"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elasticloadbalancing:CreateListener",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteListener",
            "elasticloadbalancing:CreateRule",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteRule"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
            "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*",
            "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/net/*/*",
            "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/app/*/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "true",
                "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags",
            "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveTags"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/net/*/*/*",
            "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener/app/*/*/*",
            "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener-rule/net/*/*/*",
            "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:listener-rule/app/*/*/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elasticloadbalancing:AddTags"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*",
            "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/net/*/*",
            "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:loadbalancer/app/*/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "elasticloadbalancing:CreateAction": [
                    "CreateTargetGroup",
                    "CreateLoadBalancer"
                ]
            },
            "Null": {
                "aws:RequestTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyLoadBalancerAttributes",
            "elasticloadbalancing:SetIpAddressType",
            "elasticloadbalancing:SetSecurityGroups",
            "elasticloadbalancing:SetSubnets",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteLoadBalancer",
            "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroup",
            "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyTargetGroupAttributes",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DeleteTargetGroup"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "Null": {
                "aws:ResourceTag/elbv2.k8s.aws/cluster": "false"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets",
            "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:*:*:targetgroup/*/*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elasticloadbalancing:SetWebAcl",
            "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyListener",
            "elasticloadbalancing:AddListenerCertificates",
            "elasticloadbalancing:RemoveListenerCertificates",
            "elasticloadbalancing:ModifyRule"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

These above things were applied successfully, plus I've also edited the configmap file of aws-auth:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::acc_id:role/ROLE-FOR-STAGE-ME-DS-EKS-WORKER
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
    - groups:
      - system:serviceaccounts:kube-system
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::acc_id:role/AmazonEKSLoadBalancerControllerRole
      username: system:serviceaccount:kube-system:aws-load-balancer-controller
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-10-05T12:18:19Z"
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "36251668"
  uid: b83e4116-ff0c-41e9-8507-2ba68c11f1dd
```

and that's the **policy usage** of AWSLoadBalancerControllerIAMPolicy

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this does not help you directly but I have a working example of ALB with terraform which includes the policies and configs. The first glimpse of your config seems fine to me but you can double-check with my example.
https://github.com/ishuar/terraform-aws-eks/tree/main/examples/cluster_with_alb/kubernetes-alb-config

Answer (score 0):

The main question here for a quick diagnose:
 **Does the AWS IAM role is eventually being used?**

You can see it when you enter the aws console UI inside the role details you should see **when it was last used** (don't trust on the column in the external view where you can see all roles with a search bar, I saw some delays in the update there).

**If role is never used:**

1. Check the arn that was passed to the service account annotation.
2. Check the namespace and service account name passed to the trust relationship - put wildcard on both for a quick debug.
3. Check the OIDC related values that you passed to the trust relationship, I would just quickly change it to trust all clusters in this account for a quick debug.
4. Try to assume other role with that pod via the IRSA mechanism (like you did).

**If role is used:**

Then the error should specify which action is missing in your policy, try to see if the required policy was changed in the latest versions of your tool.

In the case of aws-load-balancer controller it was really changed between [v2.4.1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4.1/docs/install/iam_policy.json) <->  [v2.6.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.6.0/docs/install/iam_policy.json).

---

(*) You haven't specified the full error, but usually it is easy to see according to the error if the role that was passed via the service account was used - you should see something like this:

```
AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::<accountId>:assumed-role/eks-alb-controller-hhfz6/1695108220719227138)
```

And not the Node's role Id.